# PHP's 'echo' does not work right

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, echo

I need to check some return values of functions, which i put in a while loop:

```
    //should be true if an error comes up (a function returns false)
    $error = false;

    while ($error == false) {
        if (!$this->check_date()) {
            $this->log('bad date');
            $error = true;
            break;
        }

        if (!$this->check_location()) {
            $this->log('bad location');
            $error = true;
            break;
        }

        if (!$this->check_abc()) {
            $this->log('bad abc');
            $error = true;
            break;
        }

        //... more if's

        break;
    }

    //No error - great
    if ($error == false) {
        //Answer to my AJAX call
        echo "true";
    } else {
        $this->log('-There is an error-');
    }
```

So, whats the problem ?

I dont get an output to my AJAX call

[image]

BUT if i put an echo "test";  here:

```
        //... more if's

        break;
    }

echo "test";

    //No error - great
    if ($error == false) {
        //Answer to my AJAX call
        echo "true";
    } else {
        $this->log('-There is an error-');
    }
```

i get the following back :

[image]

So, whats the matter of this ?

AJAX code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: "do=this",
        success: function (answer) {

            console.log(answer);

        },
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {                
            console.log("error" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Thank you for your help :)

**SOLUTION** It seems like PHP misunderstands the "true" - so we need to enode it, for example as a JSON string:

```
    //No error - great
    if ($error == false) {
        //Answer to my AJAX call
        echo json_encode("true");
    } else {
        $this->log('-There is an error-');
    }
```

Comment: *"I dont get an output to my AJAX call"* - Maybe there's something wrong in what you didn't post, the ajax stuff.

Comment: Whats the point of having this in a while loop? / @FunkFortyNiner Nice day for the cacti no?

Comment: @Xorifelse it sure is buddy :-)

Comment: @Xorifelse to break up if an error occurs, so that the following functions are not executed.

Comment: @MickaelLeger there is an break at the bottom of the loop...

Comment: Just a note: Think about using [`json_encode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) before `echo`ing your result. Like `echo json_encode('true');`

Comment: Good point sorry ! Thought it was an other if

Comment: If you got better solutions for this - they are very welcome.

Comment: You get one downvote and you give up?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. We'd need a reproducing example.
Also, please try with my `json_encode` advice, perhaps PHP performs a kind of cast of your "true".

Comment: use `data: {'do': 'this'},`. And there is no point in using a loop. That little overhead is saved by saving multiple request if you found out that you have more errors on the input so multiple requests are not needed so you can handle all the errors in 1 go. So `json_encode(['errors' => $errors])` all the errors, if there are any.

Comment: @AnthonyB thank you, i will do. I try your json_encode now.

Comment: @AnthonyB json_encode works - it really seams like, as PHP misunderstands my output. If you want, create a question. Sorry guys for not following the "how to ask a question" - guide this time.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You respond to an AJAX request, so you should use [`json_encode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to be sure to return a valid json.

```
<?php
echo json_encode('true');
```

In you case it's only a string, but PHP is doing a kind of cast, so it's more safe to use json_encode.